# Slider with manual controls is not autoplaying - possibly an issue with setInterval behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a pure JavaScript slider using timeouts to switch slide automatically. As far as that goes, all is fine.

However, when I tried to add control buttons, they are not working. Instead, it waits until the page is set to switch (as defined by the timeout) before moving on.

What could be the cause of this, and how could I fix it? I have tried using the `clearTimeout()` method when the button is pressed (before trying to make the slide change), but to no avail.

Below is my code:

```js
document.body.onload = () => {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
  var prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
  var currentSlide = function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      if (items[j].className === "item active") {
        return j;
      }
    }
  }


  function slideShow(currentslideinner) {
    if (currentslideinner == undefined) {
      currentslideinner = 0;
    } else {
      clearInterval(abc);
    }
    var abc = setInterval(function() {
      items[currentslideinner].classList.remove("active");
      currentslideinner++;
      if (currentslideinner > items.length - 1) {
        currentslideinner = 0;
      }
      console.log(currentslideinner);
      items[currentslideinner].classList.add("active");
    }, 4000);


  }

  slideShow();

  nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let currentSlide1 = currentSlide();
    if (currentSlide1 < items.length - 1) {
      items[currentSlide1].classList.remove("active");
      items[currentSlide1 + 1].classList.add("active");
      slideShow(currentSlide1 + 1);
    }

  });

  prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let currentSlide1 = currentSlide();
    if (currentSlide1 > 0) {
      items[currentSlide1].classList.remove("active");
      items[currentSlide1 - 1].classList.add("active");
      slideShow(currentSlide1 - 1);

    }
  });
}
```

```css
*,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.item.active {
  display: block;
  animation: fadesIn 2000ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadesIn 2000ms forwards;
}

@keyframes fadesIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.item div.carouselContent {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.item div.carouselContent .title {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item div.carouselContent .description {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: brown;
}

#item4 {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Awesome Carousel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Awesome Carousel</h1>
      <div id="carousel">
        <div id="next" class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-3x"></div>
        <div id="prev" class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x"></div>
        <div id="item1" class="item active">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 2</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item ">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 3</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item4" class="item">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 4</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f65431e04.js"></script>
    <script></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe just use something like Bootstrap sliders? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#carouselExampleControls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
document.body.onload = () => {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
  var prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
  var currentSlide = function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      if (items[j].className === "item active") {
        return j;
      }
    }
  }

  var abc, currentslideinner;
  function slideShow(currentslideinner) {
    if (currentslideinner == undefined) {
      currentslideinner = 0;
    }
    clearInterval(abc);
    abc = setInterval(function() {
      items[currentslideinner].classList.remove("active");
      currentslideinner++;
      if (currentslideinner > items.length - 1) {
        currentslideinner = 0;
      }
      console.log(currentslideinner);
      items[currentslideinner].classList.add("active");
    }, 4000);
  }

  slideShow();

  nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let currentSlide1 = currentSlide();
    items[currentSlide1].classList.remove("active");
    if (currentSlide1 < items.length - 1) {
      items[currentSlide1 + 1].classList.add("active");
      slideShow(currentSlide1 + 1);
    } else {
      items[0].classList.add("active");
      slideShow(0);
    }
  });

  prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let currentSlide1 = currentSlide();
    if (currentSlide1 > 0) {
      items[currentSlide1].classList.remove("active");
      items[currentSlide1 - 1].classList.add("active");
      slideShow(currentSlide1 - 1);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
*,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.item.active {
  display: block;
  animation: fadesIn 2000ms forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadesIn 2000ms forwards;
}

@keyframes fadesIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.item div.carouselContent {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.item div.carouselContent .title {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item div.carouselContent .description {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: brown;
}

#item4 {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Awesome Carousel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Awesome Carousel</h1>
      <div id="carousel">
        <div id="next" class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-3x"></div>
        <div id="prev" class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x"></div>
        <div id="item1" class="item active">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 2</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item ">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 3</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item4" class="item">
          <div class="carouselContent">
            <div class="title">Lorem ipsum 4</div>
            <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing
              elit. Quasi non possimus libero, ea quas magnam odio quidem fugiat porro
              in! Maxime laboriosam corporis voluptatum totam enim voluptates aliquid!
              Vero, aliquid!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f65431e04.js"></script>
    <script></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your code is working fine can you please explain to me what was my fault. I think that I was not  clearing interval when the slide is zero and I have declared variable abc inside the founction

Comment: For me, it was actually working fine except when I reached the last slide, i.e clicking next on the fourth slide didn't take me to the first slide, but rather did nothing. I saw that this was because the line `if (currentSlide1 < items.length - 1) {` had no `else` statement. The rest of the changes were mostly to neaten the code, or I just added when I was debugging/trying to see what wasn't working.